# T_1 separation axiom in topology

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking separation axiom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264366/checking-separation-axiom)

Let $R$ be an topology on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $V$ open if and only if either $0\in V$ or $2\notin V$. Would you help me how to check whether $R$ satisfiying separation axiom  $T_1$ .

My work: Let $V$ be open set containing $2$. By definition, $0\in V$. Note that $0\neq 2$. Since for all $V$ open that containing $2$, we have $0\in V$ then $T_1$ is not satisfied.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question - [you should post that answer, which is explicitly allowed here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Also, I don't suppose you're the same user as the one who [posted this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/264366/264)?  If so, I can merge your accounts if you'd like.

Comment: What are people's opinions about closing this as a duplicate?

Comment: @Zev Chonoles : No. I just check if my argument correct or not, and also get a constructive comment. I'm a different user

Comment: @ZevChonoles: How about my answer? Is it correct? Or i have to add some additional argument?

Comment: It looks just fine (though I, personally, would want to explicitly justify that it does indeed define a topology). As Zev says, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @ZevChonoles:  I would close it as a duplicate.  The other one asked more questions, but this one is included.

Comment: @Zev: I’d leave it open long enough to give *ask* a reasonable chance to write up and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The space is $T_0$: if $x \neq y$ then at least one of them, say $x$, is unequal to $2$. In that case $\{x\}$ is open and does not contain $y$, and so $T_0$ has been shown.

The space is not $T_1$: let $x = 0$ and $y = 2$. If $X$ were $T_1$ there would be an open set $O$ that contains $2$ but not $0$. But if $O$ contains $2$, by the definition of the topology it *must* contain $0$, so we have a contradiction.